Question about lasers

In a laser, how the beam is almost non-divergent?
When stimulated emission happens , does it copy the photons which is used for the medium to get pumped, or does it copy the photons of spontaneous emission?


Given that the laser output is radically different from the pump light, you should review what stimulated emission is.

All laser diodes have large divergence due to tiny aperature. A small lens is used at the output.

A laser contains an active medium that produces light such as a gas discharge or a PN junction. An energy source excites atoms. They produce photons when they decay. Decay may happen spontaneously. Or if a photon comes by, it may stimulate the atom to decay and produce an identical photon. The medium is chosen to have a long excited lifetime so that the chance of stimulated emission is maximized.
The laser also contains a cavity with mirrors. There is a path in the cavity that light can follow that retraces itself. Light of just the right wavelength will have traveled an integer number of wavelengths, and so be at the same phase when it returns.
When a laser is first turned on, all the photons are from spontaneous decay. Some of those photons happen to be on just the right path and with just the right wavelength to trace a repeat path. Most will not.
Any of those photons may stimulate emission. But most will pass through the medium once and be lost. The ones that happen to be on the right path will pass through multiple times. They have a much better chance of being copied. Within a very short time, almost all the photons being copied are on the right path. There are many photons in the cavity, so very few atoms decay spontaneously.

People generally think about light in terms of rays, as though light consisted of point particles whose trajectories are straight lines. Most of the time, this is a good enough approximation. Camera lenses are designed with it.
But light is a described by an electromagnetic wave. It extends over a region of space. It diffracts. Light can also be described by photons. The uncertainty principal ensures that photons extend over a region. Often the region is large enough that a photon can go through two slits at the same time.
It is possible for light to form a uniform plane wave that extends sideways to infinity. This wave has a perfectly defined direction. It is perfectly collimated.
If such a wave passes through an aperture, it no longer extends to infinity. Solving the classical Maxwell equations for a wave with the aperture as a boundary condition shows that the wave is no longer perfectly collimated. It diffracts.
Likewise, the Uncertainty Principle ensures that photons with a small sideways uncertainty in position must have a large sideways uncertainty in momentum. The beam cannot be perfectly collimated. The beam diffracts.
An infinite beam might have a bright central maximum that fades away far from the axis. This is much like a beam that passed through an aperture. A Gaussian beam is (to a good approximation) an example of such a beam.
A Gaussian beam has good properties for a laser, such as a large central maximum that smoothly fades away. Most laser cavities are designed to produce them. Two slightly concave spherical mirrors facing each other match the shape of the wave fronts of a Gaussian beam.
If a Gaussian beam happens to develop in such a cavity, it will reflect back and forth and grow. It will have the required intensity profile, with a bright central maximum. If it did not, diffraction would not be just right to match the shape of the mirrors.
Lasers have finite diameter optics. The diameter of the optics must be large enough that the edge of the beam has faded away to almost $0$.
Typically a Gaussian beam is designed to be as close as possible to collimated. The divergence angle is measured in milliradians.
